# Сложение или объединение запросов

Tags: sql

Как сложить результаты двух запросов или объединить эти запросы для получения результата

Есть два запроса:
1)

```
SELECT point, predprijatie, SUM(ostatok)
FROM ostatky
```

2)

```
SELECT (SUM(prihod) - SUM(rashod))
FROM main
```

Нужно просуммировать результат этих двух запросов или как то запросы объединить...Как бы это сделать?

Comment: Для начала, у вас не верные ( логически и синтаксически ) запросы

Comment: а что тут неверного?подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: 1. Без `group by` - `SELECT point, predprijatie` не имеет смысла ( в вашем случае - совсем ), и в многих SQL СУБД даст ошибку
2. Объединение возможно только при одинаковом кол-ве полей

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Что именно попробуете?)

1. Вы используете агрегатную функцию по всей таблице - от какой строки вы ожидаете `point, predprijatie`? Почему вы думаете что они будут именно от этой строки?
2. Некоторые СУБД позволяют получить не агрегированные поля ( впринципии, т.к. это будет значения из последней строки, что аналогично некоторой не существующей функции LAST_VAL( column ) ), но в данном случае ( вся таблица -> в одну строку ) это совсем не ясная цель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из предположений того, что вам нужно:

```
select
(SELECT SUM(ostatok) FROM ostatky) + (SELECT SUM(prihod) - SUM(rashod) FROM main)
```

Answer (score 0):

В PL/SQL можно сложить результаты двух курсоров.